# How to align text based on its box size using PHP Imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I'm puting some texts in a image at specifics positions X and Y. I also trying to align the text like we do in a box on Photoshop, but when I use $draw->setTextAlignment() I got a different result. See bellow:

**Current result:**

[image: Current alignment]

**Desired result:**

[image: Desired alignment]

The text and its properties (font name, size, color, etc) are dynamic, so the size can vary.

Can someone help me with that?

**Code:**

```
<?php

$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeColor(new \ImagickPixel('black'));
$draw->setFillColor(new \ImagickPixel('red'));
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$draw->setFontSize(36);

// First box
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_LEFT);
$draw->annotation(250, 75, "First line\nSecond Line");

// Second box
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
$draw->annotation(250, 210, "First line\nSecond Line");

// Third box
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_RIGHT);
$draw->annotation(250, 330, "First line\nSecond Line");

$draw->line(250, 0, 250, 500);

$image = new \Imagick();
$image->newImage(500, 500, new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image->drawImage($draw);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

*p.s. The vertical lines are used on these examples only to show the alignment differences.*

Comment: can anyone help me in the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085268/how-to-draw-a-long-text-to-a-image-without-wrapping-it-using-imagick-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found the solution!** See the result image and the explanation:

[image: See the text boxes properly aligned]

We can query the `$draw` object using `Imagick::queryFontMetrics` in order to know the text width and height - it also returns other information's not needed for this purpose, see:

[image: Array returned by Imagick::queryFontMetrics]

The *X coordinate* is the first argument of `ImagickDraw::annotation` and specifies where the text should be drawn on the horizontal axis of image.

With the width of text in our hands (`textWidth`) we can can calculate the correct *X coordinate* of text doing the following for each text alignment:

- **Left** - use the *X coordinate* as is - nothing to do.
- **Center** - sum the *X coordinate* + half width of text.
- **Right** - sum the *X coordinate* + the entire width of text.

See the code in action:

```
<?php
$image = new \Imagick();

$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeColor(new \ImagickPixel('black'));
$draw->setFillColor(new \ImagickPixel('red'));
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$draw->setFontSize(36);
$text = "First line\nSecond Line";

// First box
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_LEFT);
$draw->annotation(250, 75, $text);

// Second box
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);
$draw->annotation(250 + ($metrics['textWidth'] / 2), 210, $text);


// Third box
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_RIGHT);
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);
$draw->annotation(250 + ($metrics['textWidth']), 330, $text);

$draw->line(250, 0, 250, 500);

$image->newImage(500, 500, new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image->drawImage($draw);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

It outputs the image with the texts properly aligned.

For more info see the following references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php
- http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/queryFontMetrics
- http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.annotation.php

Comment: You just saved me like a week of research. Thanks a lot!